# Ordering Wordpress posts by multiple meta values

Tags: php, wordpress

Using `get_posts()`, I need to first retrieve posts that fall on a certain day (the day is set by a custom field - just the date, not time).  I do this by using a meta key/value.  Then, I need to order these posts based on the time of day (which is a separate custom field, just time, not date).  So essentially I need to pull in all the events that fall on a given day, and order them according to the time.

First I grab the day, using a custom field:

```
if ( get_field('festival_day') ) {
  $day_stamp = get_field('festival_day');
}
```

Then I set my arguments for the query:

```
$args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'event',
        'meta_key' => 'event_date',
        'meta_value' => $day_stamp
    );
    $events = get_posts( $args );
```

So.. the question is, how do I query the other custom field (which is the start time), and then sort by that time?  The time field key is `event_start_time`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can user [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to retrieve your events and you can query it something like below:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key' => 'event_start_time',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'event_start_time',
            'value' => 'yourValue_here',
            'compare' => '>='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'event_date',
            'value' => $day_stamp,
            'compare' => '='
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

**UNTESTED** but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
Check this code, it should work to sort your post according to time from resulting post of day.

$args = array(
'post_type'     => 'post',
'posts_per_page'    => -1,
'meta_key' => 'event_start_time',
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
'order' => 'ASC',
'meta_query'=> array(
array(
'key' => 'event_date',
'value' => $day_stamp,
'compare' => 'IN'
)
)
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
echo '<ul>';
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
$the_query->the_post();     
echo '<li>'. get_the_title().'</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
} else {
// no posts found
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works!  I think my problem was assuming you HAD to have a meta value if you had a meta key.  Thanks again for the solution.

Comment: Well...  It worked with the current posts I had on the page.  When I added a new one, it showed up at the end of the feed, in the wrong time slot.

Comment: where did you place above code? i suggest you to put it into custom template..as it is working fine for me..i have checked it as well..

Comment: Ah ha!  I figured it out.  I'm using the ACF plugin with the Date/Time Picker Add-on.  There is an option, when using the Date/Time field, to ONLY use the "Time Picker".  This does, in fact, set the time, BUT the date defaults to the day you published the post.  I had posts published yesterday, and even though the "TIME" was later in the day, the posts I published this morning were still showing up AFTER.  Hope that makes sense.  The solution was to change the custom field back to picking the DATE and TIME, that way the DATE is correct.

Comment: Once I did that, and used your code, the sorting worked properly.  So thank you again!